# Download file in the 'Save As' mode using window.open

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a legacy code in my hand that uses the bellow logic to download the file

```
downloadXls = (filepath) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const response = { file: filepath }
      window.open(response.file, "_blank");
    }, 100);
  }
```

I do wanna know if has a way to open the 'SAVE AS dialog box', currently the file is being download normally in the downloads folder.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the browser is the one who decides if the "Save as" dialog should open.

Comment: Yes; how a browser handles downloads is browser- and config-specific.